# Mesh rigged to skeleton deformed in pose

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I have a human body mesh and a skeleton which I got from modding kit for a computer game. I am trying to mod a backpack into the game.

I followed a tutorial and parented a plain cube (my backpack prototype) to the skeleton. When I go into pose mode and move any bone from the skeleton, the cube gets distorted.

[image]
[image]

To check what I'm doing wrong, I imported an existing backpack from the game and did the same steps. When I change pose here, the backpack keeps its normal form.

So what could be the difference between my cube and the imported backpack?

What I did so far:

- Parent my cube to the skeleton, selecting "with empty groups".
- Go to weight paint, transfer weights from the human body mesh to my
  backpack. There I selected "create Data -> nearest vertex" and
  changed "Source Layers selection" to  "By name". I left the rest to
  defaults. After this step, my cube had a vertex selected, as shown by
  the bright circle in the picture below. Before that, no vertex had
  such a circle.

[image]

The vertex selected is exactly the same that gets selected when I do the same steps with the existing backpack. It's a skeleton bone in the human's foot, because that's where the origins of both the skeleton and the backpack meshes are. So I assume "nearest neighbor" will always select this bone.

Why do poses distort my cube?

Edit: By default, the cube is blue in weightpaint:

[image]

So I choose the toe bone and paint the cube red:

[image]

The result: the cube is no longer distorted, but its position is off.

Comment: why did you even transfer weights? Just paint the neccessary bones yourself. You can check if the leg bone deforms the cube by selecting it while in weight paint mode. Also look for a tutorial on armature weight painting to learn the basic mechanics.

Comment: I updated my post. I have played around with weight painting before. I made the whole cube red for every single bone. This actually fixed the deformation but it also moved the cubes position. When I import it into the game and run around with a character, the cube moves back and forth while running. If it's all blue, the cube stays in position but deforms while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters which bone is weight painted. When I selected the bone closest to the backpack (a spine bone in the person's upper back) and then painted the backpack red, it stayed in position and did not deform anymore.

Answer (score 0):

parenting or joining the backpack mesh to the mesh instead of the skeleton might be the right move for your need. When you parent the whole mesh to the skeleton it references all bones, you can also try parenting to a root bone. Joining the backpack mesh to the humanoid mesh will allow you to also make the correct deformations and parenting to the bones. I've found the humane rigging blender tutorial here youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ&list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB. I hope this helps. Also consider giving a try to the blender cloud there is a lot of useful examples and tutorials. store.blender.org/product/membership